# Cannot use minified vue component bundle in rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I am new to `Vue.js` I have created a minified js bundle for my Vue component and placed it into rails `vendor/assets/javascript` folder but every time I run my project it gives this warning:

[image]

The minified bundle was made with this command:
`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name @smondalkreeti/side-panel ./src/main.js`

This is `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

export default new Vue({
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is my `application.html.erb` in rails application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todo</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <% if !flash.empty? %>
      <%= flash.each do |key, msg| %>
        <div><%= msg %></div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my `app/assets/javascripts/pack/application.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const App = require('../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/side-panel.umd.min');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  const app = new Vue({
    el,
    render: (h) => h(App.default)
  });

  console.log(app);
});
```

I am confused here how to show the Vue component in my rails application?

Comment: The .mount(“#app”) line will be executed when the module is evaluated, i.e. when it is first imported. You’ll need to make sure that happens within the eventListener callback.

Comment: @rossta great| it worked, but now I'm trying to import the minified css, I imported the css file in `app/assets/javascripts/pack/application.js`, but is giving an error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.66dc854e.eot'`. I installed `@mdi/font` package it is still not working

Comment: Generally its best loading such JS just before the closing </body> tag, saves you a lot of potential hassle. Also make sure the div you create has the app id.

Comment: @NickM that thing has been resolved, can help me with the minified css issue, that I mentioned in the above comment?

Comment: Seems like a path issue coming from the ./fonts.... relative path. You don't know exactly from which working directory that relative path is evaluated. Try playing with it or use absolute path. In my CSS I have a fonts/ dir in the public/ directory and I hardcode the paths with /fonts/whatever.eot.